# How do I pass a variable from blade file to controller in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have `ProjectController` that fetches data from the database and passes it to a blade file. One of the data items is the `project_id`. I want to pass the `project _id` from the blade file to another controller `BidController`.

**ProjectController.php**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $project = Project::find($id);
    return view('project.show',['project'=>$project]);
}
```

**show.blade.php**

```
div class="card-header">PROJECT <p>{!! $project->id !!}</p></div>
```

**BidController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
     $bid = new Bid;
     $bid->project_id = $project_id;
     dd($project_id);        
}
```

The `dd();` does not output the `project_id`. I need help in passing the `project_id` from the blade file to the `BidController` method.

Comment: You pass the value as `post` or `get` method or `ajax request`

Comment: If 'project_id' is included as part of the query string of the next request into your app, then you'll find it under `$request->project_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can't directly set a model's `id` like you're doing in the line `$bid->id = $project_id;`. Are you trying to set up a relationship? That should be more like `$bid->project_id = $request->project_id;`.
2. Blade templates can't really pass things back to controllers, once they're in the browser your app is sort-of finished running. You need to create an HTML link/request on the page (like a form post request) that'll request the next thing from your app when the user clicks it.

If you want to create a button that creates a new bid for an existing project, you could do something like set up a form with a hidden field of 'project_id' that posts back to '/bids' which goes to the route 'bids.store'. You'll find 'project_id' under `$request->project-id'`.

Comment: I think so also

Answer (score 0):

You can send an `AJAX` request from Javascript:

**View**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var project_id= {!! json_encode($project->id) !!}

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url, //Your bidController route
            data: {project_id: project_id},
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown)
            },
            success: function()
            {
                console.log('successful')
            }
        });
</script>
```

This will sent the data to the controller asynchronously so the user experience doesn't get affected.

One extra point: In your Bid controller, as `project_id` is coming from the request, you'll have to use:

```
$bid->id = $request->project_id;
```

I hope it helps!

PS: I'm using JQuery for this, so you'll have to include it if you don't already have.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem :

ProjectController.php

```
public function show($id)
{
    $project = Project::findOrFail($id);
    return view('project.show',compact('project');
}
```

web.php

```
Route::post('/bids/store/{id}' , 'BidController@store')->name('bids.store');
```

show.blade.php

```
div class="card-header">PROJECT <p>{{$project->id}}</p></div>
<form action="{{route('bids.store', $project->id)}}" method="post">
```

BidController.php

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
     $bid = new Bid;
     $bid->id = $id;
     $bid->save();
     dd($id);        
}
```